# Customize Chrome Tab Width From Extension Background Script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is it possible to resize the width of the tabs for a tab opened with chrome.tabs.create, something like

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
chrome.resizetab(width); //maybe something like this
```

Also, can we make the tab title blank and show only the favicon instead of showing "Untitled"?!

Comment: No. Tabs are sized to their window. You can resize the entire window or open a new one, see `chrome.windows` API. As for title-less, you can specify a space for the title or use `pinned:true` parameter.

Comment: Oh that's interesting and pinned:true looks awesome apart from it has to be the first tab it seems which isn't 100% ideal. I'd rather it was the last tab and looked like that but maybe that's wishful thinking. The space character instead of pinned seems most promising to achieve both if it's not padded more on the right of the favicon. Thanks.

Comment: Oh just checked in devtools putting space as the title doesn't seem to work in firefox it shows the url of the page so pinned:true seems to be the only way to remove the title from the tab.

Comment: Try other characters like `\xA0` nonbreaking space.

Comment: Doesn't work as it shows any special codes in plain text. I finally got it to show a blank by typing in ALT+0160 to generate a space but then it's the same width tab with a huge blank region instead of being shrunk in any way so I do not think it's possible by changing the title text.